# Как считать двумерный массив из файла *.txt?

Tags: массивы, delphi

скажем массив вот такой:

```
  1 2 3 4 5
  6 7 6 5 4
  3 1 7 2 5
  3 1 4 2 6
  8 9 7 6 4
```

как его считать из файла?

Comment: Уточните размер известный? что есть разделителем?

Comment: полагаю, его пример и есть содержимое файла

Comment: а массив какой?
можно сделать array of char, можно сделать integer, даже String получиться может.

Пусть учится задавать вопросы если уже начал просить помощи.

Comment: Этот набор записей, находясь в текстовом файле, массивом, как таковым не является. Это вы знаете, что это массив. Поэтому вам придется считывать каждую строку и обрабатывать ее так, как вам нужно. Следовательно создаете динамический двумерный массив, и при считывании каждой строки смотрите, есть ли в ней данные, и сколько их. Если данные есть, то увеличиваете массив по вертикали, в зависимости от количество объектов увеличиваете массив по горизонтали.

Comment: >  Это вы знаете, что это массив.

Ой, я тоже знаю )

Comment: Интересное кино. Что означает SetLength(arr[i], j + 1);
Получается что в Дельфях двумерный динамический массив - не обычный прямоугольный,
а возможно в каждой строке выделение памяти под разное число элементов???
Т.е. это не прямоугольная матрица а что то вроде массива векторов-строк, каждый из которых -своей длины. Насколько понимаю в С++ такая "растяжка" невозможна

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу, вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением, а когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 2):

К чему такое занудство в комментариях? Такая задача, как правило, автоматически встречается в любом учебном/олимпиадном задании )

Все просто:

```
var
  f: text;
  arr: array [0..4, 0..4] of integer;
  i, j: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, 'c:\1.txt');
  Reset(f);
  i := 0;
  while not Eof(f) do begin
    j := 0;
    while not Eoln(f) do begin
      Read(f, arr[i, j]);
      Inc(j);
    end;
    ReadLn(f);
    Inc(i);
  end;
  CloseFile(f);

  ...
end.
```

Если размер массива заранее не известен, то надо будет еще на ходу растягивать массив:

```
var
  f: text;
  arr: array of array of integer;
  i, j, w: integer;
begin
  AssignFile(f, 'c:\1.txt');
  Reset(f);
  i := -1;
  while not Eof(f) do begin
    Inc(i);
    SetLength(arr, i + 1);
    j:= -1;
    while not Eoln(f) do begin
      Inc(j);
      SetLength(arr[i], j + 1);
      Read(f, arr[i, j]);
    end;
    ReadLn(f);
  end;
  CloseFile(f);

  ...

end.
```

Comment: а мне лень было код писать :*

Comment: полезно же с утра размяться

Comment: я с утра себя в зеркале не узнал... какая там разминка...  
порядок действий описал, и уже хорошо)